# Como desativar a atualização automática do Java?

Tags: java, windows, jvm

Como desativar a atualização do Java 7 64 bits? Entrei no painel de controle do Java e não aparece a aba update.

Obs: Não posso atualizar minha versão.

Comment: Quando você abre o que aparece? Porque é na aba update ou atualização, caso seu windows seja em português.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar disto ser altamente desaconselhável (Java costuma ter vulnerabilidades descobertas com frequência e pode comprometer todo computador) você pode desligar as atualizações pelo utilitário do Windows `msconfig.exe`.

[image: System Configurarion]

Resposta obtida à partir [dessa pergunta no SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/241147/20555), o que eu fico pensando se é *on-topic* (talvez, já que não temos SUpt). Lá tem outras formas para obter o mesmo resultado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).